# What's the correct term for the "->" syntax in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax

What's the correct name for the "arrow" syntax in PHP, used when referencing an object, e.g.

```
$this->value = "test";
```

What's the "->" really called?
One of those "really-hard-to-google" terms.

Comment: It's just a kind of syntax, does it have a name?

Comment: Good see there's as much confusion as I was expecting.  I think I'll stick with "arrow" colloquially though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`

...but everyone calls it an arrow.

---

Hint: run this in the PHP CLI: `->;`

Extra credit: now what's `::` called?

Comment: heh... at least that's easier to google for than `::`, isn't it (eventually you find "scope resolution operator" for that one).

Answer (score 1):

Good Question. The "->" is called an Arrow Operator.

References:
http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is referred to as a Single Arrow Operator, whereas the => is the Double Arrow Operator!

Answer (score 0):

dynamic data access operatore ( -> )
static data access operatore ( :: )